# How do I change resource_uri on objects when I have changed the url to use a non-PK field?

Tags: django, tastypie

Following the [instructions in the tastypie cookbook](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-non-pk-data-for-your-urls), I've changed the URL used to access my "Job" model to be referenced by UUID instead of PK:

```
class JobResource(ModelResource):
    owner = fields.ForeignKey('job.api.UserResource', 'user')
    inputs = fields.ManyToManyField('job.api.JobInputResource', 'inputs', full=True)
    outputs = fields.ManyToManyField('job.api.JobOutputResource', 'outputs', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Job.objects.all()

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<guid>[\w\d_.-]+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
        ]
```

However, the `resource_uri` in the related inputs and objects does not reflect this change, still referencing the PK sourced URL. Found [this issue](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/pull/313) and a corresponding, resolving commit (1367d7a45587b2af9969d16c3c641a255a8d5b8e) that seem directly relevant to my plight, but have not been able to find doc re: how to actually get the `resource_uri`s to change.